# Back-end validation of form being ignored

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate the data being entered into a form submission that I'm processing with PHP, first to make sure the fields were filled in, after to make sure the data is right but for some reason all that seems to be just getting ignored and the data is getting submitted to the DB no matter what I try to do.

```
// example of validation (this is just duplicated for 4 fields)
if (isset($_POST["fullname"]) && !empty($_POST["fullname"])) {
  header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/error');
} else {
  // Trying to get it to redirect at all
  header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/error');
}

$email = $_POST['email'];
// using google code email validation
include('EmailAddressValidator.php');
$validator = new EmailAddressValidator;
if ($validator->check_email_address($email)) {
    // Email address is technically valid
} else {
    header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/error');
}

// If this line is reached, submit the data to the DB but there's no way      this line should be reached because the very first if & else statement should send it to the error page.
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Been trying to fix this for hours at this point.

Comment: Redirecting with header doesn't stop the process, it just sends a header, add `exit();` if you want the process to finish.

Comment: You don't need `isset` and `!empty`, `!empty` will suffice.

Comment: @JonStirling has put his finger on it.  the header() statement does not stop execution.  Your code keeps running right past header().  If you want execution to stop after header(), you have to make it stop there.

Comment: @JonStirling but should I not be re-directed to the error page? Any time I've used the same code before this has been the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `exit;` after redirecting with header.please see example below:

```
header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/error');exit;
```

Below is example of how you should submit your form:

```
// example of validation (this is just duplicated for 4 fields)
if (isset($_POST["fullname"]) && isset($_POST["email"])) {
    // using google code email validation
    include('EmailAddressValidator.php');
    $validator = new EmailAddressValidator;

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (empty($_POST["fullname"]) && !$validator->check_email_address($email)) {
        header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/error');exit;
    } else {
        // enter into data here
    }
}
```

Comment: Was missing the `exit` intentional?

Comment: @JonStirling added :)

Answer (score -1):

first make the first if OR not AND...if (isset($_POST["fullname"]) || !empty($_POST["fullname"]))
second you must say if ($validator->check_email_address($email))
//insert in DB

Comment: Why make it an `or`?

Comment: because i think that you dont want an empty username....and a username with space value " " can be set

Comment: I would assume the inverse, since the conditional is written the way it is.

Comment: In your example, as long as the key is set, it will pass... and if it's not set, then it''s always going to be empty.